# Script a print job to run at a specified interval (awesome party)

Tags: windows, linux, scripting, printing

Hey SO! This weekend my roommate and I are throwing an office-themed party. We have a water cooler filled with beer, staplers in jello shots, etc. AND - we have a big copier/laser printer. I want it to spew out TPS reports onto the dance floor. This would occur at a specified interval.

The printer drivers are installed on both my Windows and Linux partitions. From either OS, what would be an awesome way to script this? My first thought is use the Documents functionality of .NET and just print from Word, but this seems like a little too much work. (I mean, probably 15 minutes when it could be done in 5). I'm familiar with batch and bash scripting but am not aware of any command-line interfaces that Word (or Adobe Reader, etc.) exposes for things like this. I'm asking mostly because I'm looking for new and interesting ways to approach the problem, rather than just sticking to my C/C++/C# comfort zone. What do you think?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind preparing your document in a format that CUPS can support (at least [CUPS can support PDF](http://www.cups.org/articles.php?L261+TFAQ+Q), so there's one very easy option) then you can use simple command line tools to do your task:

```
while true ; do sleep 1800 ; lp ~/Documents/TPS_Coversheet.pdf ; done
```

If you want to schedule them by something other than "sleep 1800" or similar simple tools, you can put `lp ~/Documents/TPS_Coversheet.pdf` into your `crontab(5)` file with a huge array of possibilities for specifying the time. (Almost too many.) You can edit your `crontab(5)` file by using the `crontab(1)` command: `crontab -e`